# Can't Connect to the table azure SQL in given DB connection using .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

My question is the Azure DB connection is working perfectly but when i use the sample Todo by given in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase

so i have already table in the database called "PhotoTable" but every time i run the sample (asp.net)it creates it own table ( Todoes table)in my DB ( DB is already i created and its connect fine with my existing DB) so the issue is its not connecting with mt table , i have done changing the controller and all other stuff , but it dosen't work, if anyone knows how to connect with existing table please kindly let me know , thanks ( if more information needed please let me know, i have added the screenshot of my table list and the table i need to connect i have highlighted with red)
[image]

Comment: Did you give the right link? That link is about Azure Storage , but your question is about Azure SQL DB.

Comment: The sample you provided do not need to use azure sql db and if you have existing tables , then you can just write an ADO.NET repository layer on top of it. Your controller can call these repository layers for DB operation.

Comment: @Lee Liu I am so sorry for submitting the incorrect link the correct link suppose to be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase ( i have updated my question with the correct link now, thank you for trying to help me, hope above details will support to answer the question i have, please let me know your answers , thank you

Comment: @Joey Cai, I am so sorry for submitting the incorrect link the correct link suppose to be learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/… ( i have updated my question with the correct link now, thank you for trying to help me, hope above details will support to answer the question i have, please let me know your answers , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/661053/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Map) about how to connect with an existing table in the database.

Below is `Student` class with the same attributes and properties as of the table.

```
public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

The class `StudentMap` is used to map with the existing table in the database.

```
public class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
    {
        public int MapID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public StudentMap()
        {
            // Table & parimary key Mappings
            this.ToTable("StudentMap");
            this.HasKey(t => t.ID);
        }

    }
```

The `SchoolContext` is the reference to the database. In this code, we are using the `StudentMap` declared above for configuration.

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext() : base("SchoolContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StudentMap> StudentMaps { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<StudentMap>().HasKey(x => new { x.MapID });
        }
    }
```

**Note**: Set the different key in `Student` and `StudentMap` class so that the `schoolcontext` could distinguish them correctly.